# how to schedule a quartz job with scala

Tags: scala, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to get the most simple example of a quartz job running in Scala.

configure() gets executed once when my module is loaded.

```
lazy val quartz = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultScheduler

override def configure() = {
  val Job = new Job {
    override def execute(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) = {
      println("Event")
    }
  }

  val job = JobBuilder.newJob(Job.getClass)
    .withIdentity("Job", "Group")
    .build

  val trigger: Trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .newTrigger
    .withIdentity("Trigger", "Group")
    .withSchedule(
      CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/5 * * * * ?"))
    .build

  quartz.start
  quartz.scheduleJob(job, trigger)
}
```

However, I get an error message when this code runs.

```
2015-09-29 15:27:05,015 [DefaultQuartzScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread] ERROR
org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger - An error occured instantiating job to be executed. job= 'Group.Job'
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Problem instantiating class 'com.search.binder.SearchModule$$anon$1'
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:58) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.simpl.PropertySettingJobFactory.newJob(PropertySettingJobFactory.java:69) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.initialize(JobRunShell.java:127) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:375) [quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.search.binder.SearchModule$$anon$1
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleJobFactory.newJob(SimpleJobFactory.java:56) ~[quartz-2.2.1.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.search.binder.SearchModule$$anon$1.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

Does anyone have an "as simple as possible" example of quartz scheduler running in Scala?

Comment: Your code works correctly when pasted into `object MyMain extends App{...}`, I think the problem is in `configure() gets executed once when my module is loaded`. You should write how you are calling `configure()`.

Comment: And here's the code I tested. http://pastebin.com/ySWikJqR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that quartz is trying to instantiate a new instance of `Job` but it can't find its constructor because the class you are passing via `Job.getClass` is an anonymous class. Try defining it as follows:

```
class MyJob extends Job {
  override def execute(jobExecutionContext: JobExecutionContext) = {
    println("Event")
  }
}
```

And then:

```
val job = JobBuilder.newJob(classOf[MyJob])
  .withIdentity("Job", "Group")
  .build
```

Comment: Tried that - same error.  Also tried switching to lazy val quartz = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler

Comment: Seems strange to me that this didn't work, I found the same also in a play2 quartz module: https://github.com/mchv/play2-quartz/blob/master/app/utils/QuartzScheduler.scala#L46

Comment: Ok if I do this, and then I take that MyJob class outside of the configure() function (move it to the root level), then it works.  So java doesn't like that the class is declared inside the configure function.  I will mark this as answer.