# Task schedualing over long time intervals in scala

Tags: multithreading, scala, scheduling

I have a series of tasks that have to be executed at certain points in time (long time in the future, days and possibly weeks). My plan was to create for each a thread that waits until its time is due. Since the number of tasks can be quite hi, I am concerned that those threads combined will consume a lot of resources (to do nothing/ to wait). My question is if a thread that waits consumes resources and if yes how many.

(I asume that creating a database of tasks and constantly iterating through it to see if any should be executed is even less efficient)

Comment: I would suspect that the easiest solution will be to create a service and add it to the cron to be scheduled once a day etc so it will be run once a day like a job, it more looks like to me you have job not a task which just need to be scheduled. In case of scala specific implementation I think you should look in Akka: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/scheduler.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a scala-specific issue.

The problem with having a thread wait for a long period of time is that your application might crash in the meantime or you might have a power outage or whatever.

Storing it in the database sounds like a straightforward solution to me on the other hand. Sure it would be quite time-consuming if you iterated through all entries all the time. However if you have "due" field in the database, based on which you can sort, this should be fairly efficient. Obviously you'd need to choose an appropriate database that efficiently supports such operations, but in effect, this will allow you to build a more reliable system that may continue to work correctly after the application was restarted.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to schedule a job on a specific point in time I would recommend using a job scheduler like http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/ .
It's pretty extensive and you can easily create and schedule a job like:

```
public class MyJob implements org.quartz.Job {

      public MyJob() {
      }

      public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
          System.err.println("Hello World!  MyJob is executing.");
      }
}

  JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
      .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
      .build();

  // Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds
  Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
      .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
      .startNow()
      .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
              .withIntervalInSeconds(40)
              .repeatForever())
      .build();

  // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
  scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Since it is a Java library you can of course easily use it within Scala as well (see [SO here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32855314/5190890)).

Regarding the option to use Akka (@Pavel). If you are not using Akka anyways and you only need scheduler functionality, I would go with Quartz. If you are using Akka (or plan to use it) and you only need jobs that run X weeks / days / hours from now or in a certain period, you can use Akka scheduler. If you need more complex semantics like specific dates and times I would take a look at Quartz.